# Have label disappear and save with button

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, save, uilabel

have been having trouble with getting a label to disappear and stay disappeared. So have gotten the label to disappear, but have not gotten the label to save.

Comment: Please edit your post providing more details and include your code so far.

Comment: Can you provide some information or code (or screenshots would be great)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do

```
label.isHidden = true
```

if you could provide me better details I can help out better

Comment: Well, have two different view controllers and there are different label(s) on each. Am pretty am going to need to segue them somehow, currently reading about this. And am going to try to add a button that gets not only the one view controller label to disappear, but both labels to disappear from one button. Also am trying to get hidden labels to save the .isHidden, so when for example closing out of the app, the hidden labels would stay hidden. So am currently looking into this and any further help would seriously appreciated.